# Trouble getting pip to work with Mac system Python (v2.7.10)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I currently have a package that uses my Mac's system version of Python (2.7.10, located in /usr/bin/python) as a dependency. I have tried in the past to get this package working with other versions of Python installed through Homebrew (both v2.x and v3.x), but I only found success with the system version, so I moved on. The problem is that I need pip to install a new package, but I can't get pip to work with Python v2.7.10. It seems to only recognize locations associated with my Homebrew installed Python versions.

When I type `which python` I get `/usr/bin/python`. When I just try `/usr/bin/python` in the Terminal, it opens Python with the message:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Good. This is the same result as when I try `/usr/bin/python2.7`. (I set an alias for this path to test things further: `alias pythonx="/usr/bin/python2.7"`.)

However, when I type `python --version`, I get 
`-bash: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory`. I think this is because it's still looking in the area where I installed Python with Homebrew (which I've since uninstalled). `pythonx --version` gives me `Python 2.7.10`.

When I try

`python -m pip install <package_name>`

I get:

`-bash: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory`

With pythonx, I get:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named pip`

Shouldn't these be the same?

In any case, pip does not seem to be "installed" for Python 2.7.10. I've tried to install pip using the `get-pip.py` method, but it didn't change anything. (The official site also discourages against messing with system Python, so I'm avoiding installing into /usr/bin/.)

Comment: Check your PATH by typing in `echo $PATH` in the Terminal and reply with the output. It might contain something involving Homebrew, which no longer exists.

Comment: Also, try using `pipenv` or some virtualenv. Never mess with system install python, unless 1) you know exactly what you are doing 2) it is completely necessary 3) it is usually never No. 2. In my experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I type `python --version`, I get `-bash: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory`

This is because `bash` still remembers where it saw `python` last time. To clear its memory run `hash -r`. See command `hash` in [`bash` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

> When I try
>
> `python -m pip install <package_name>`
>
> I get:
>
> `-bash: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory`

This is because `/usr/local/bin/pip` is still there and it's first in
the `$PATH` and it has `/usr/local/bin/python` as the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

I recommend to remove manually everything from `/usr/local/bin/` related to `python` and `pip`. Something like

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
rm python* pip*
```

and then [install `pip`](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing/) with `/usr/bin/python`.